# Zend Framework 2 manipulate request var before validation

Tags: zend-framework2

Is there a possibility within ZF2, to manipulate an incoming POST variable before it is validated?

I have a form, which until now receives POST-data only from our own application. Now, we want to allow an external application to post data into this form. However, we do not fully control that other application and thus the names of the variables are not identical.

Ideally, my controller should check if that other POST variable (e.g. "someVarFromExternal") exists and use that for our variable ("someVarFromMe"). This would have to happen somewhere *before* the validation.

In plain PHP this would be dead simple. Somewhere before the validation I could put this:

```
if($_POST['someVarFromExternal']){
    $_POST['someVarFromMe'] = $_POST['someVarFromExternal'];
}
```

But in ZF2 I would have to manipulate the request data, which does not seem possible. My controller looks like this:

```
public function calculateAction() {
    $form = new MyForm();

    $request = $this->getRequest();

    if ($request->isPost()) {

        $myClassObject = new MyClass();
        $form->setInputFilter($myClassObject->getInputFilter());
        $form->setData($request->getPost());

        if ($form->isValid()) {

            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Where and how could I achieve the same in ZF2?

The only other option I see is writing a custom validator which takes care of this, but it seems a bit overkill for the little exchange of variables, that I actually need.

Answer (score 1):

15 minutes later I found a solution.

The POST variables are in an ArrayObject which I retrieve with

```
$postVars=$request->getPost();
```

From this, I make a (non-private) array with getArrayCopy. And now I can manipulate the variable in question.

Finally I create a new object of type \Zend\Stdlib\Parameters from the manipulated array. This I feed to the form for validation.

My controller then looks like this:

```
public function calculateAction() {
    $form = new MyForm();

    $request = $this->getRequest();

    if ($request->isPost()) {

        $postVars=$request->getPost();
        $postVarsCopy = $postVars->getArrayCopy();
        if($postVarsCopy['someVarFromExternal']){
            $postVarsCopy['someVarFromMe'] = $postVarsCopy['someVarFromExternal'];
        }
        $data=new \Zend\Stdlib\Parameters($postVarsCopy);

        $myClassObject = new MyClass();
        $form->setInputFilter($myClassObject->getInputFilter());
        $form->setData($data);

        if ($form->isValid()) {

            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Works! If someone knows a better / more elegant way, please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

It is even more simple. It 's not necessary to create a complete copy of the post data. Look at the following example.

```
$oRequest = $this->getRequest();
if ($oRequest->getPost()->get('someVarFromExternal')) {
    $oRequest->getPost()->set('someVarFromMe', $oRequest->getPost()->get('someVarFromExternal'));
}
```

The Zend Parameters object extends the native ArrayObject class with the get and set methods. With this methods, you can easily extend your post data.